# The OnClientClick event is not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate my `contactno` control using a JavaScript function but it is not being raised before the `OnClick` event

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate() {
    var contactno = document.getElementById('contactno').value;
    if(contactno.toString.length != 7 && contactno.toString.length != 10) 
    {
        <% result.Text = "Please enter valid phone no !!"; %>
        return false;
    }

    else
        return true;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" class="loginbutton" type="submit" Text="Add" OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="submit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

When I debug it starts executing the `OnClick` function without executing the `validate()` function.

Update

When i start debugging my project it shows an error on the breakpoint on the `validate()` function stating

> This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debuggers's target code type is associated with this line.

Comment: your javascript validate function might be returning true always. As you are beginner, put alert('hi'); in couple of places inside js function and see if it is hitting. you can also put debugger; and debug using dev tools (F12).

Comment: i tried debugging this function but it doesnt even reach the first line and rather it shows some error on the breakpoint that This breakpoint will not be currently hit.....

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate() {
        var contactno = document.getElementById('contactno').value;
        if (contactno.length != 7 && contactno.length != 10) {
        <% result.Text = "Please enter valid phone no !!"; %>
        return false;
    }

    else
        return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to use contactno.length instead of  contactno.toString.length

Comment: Ya sorry my silly mistake i thought that <input type=number> will return integer so ill have to convert it to string

Comment: the validate() function is still not invoked it directly jumps to the OnClick event

Answer (score 1):

try do it without the return.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" class="loginbutton" type="submit" Text="Add" OnClientClick="validate()" OnClick="submit_Click"></asp:Button>
```